# returning local variables by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, scope, static

i have the following code:

```
        int& func(int i){
          int *p = &i;
          return *p;
        }

        int& func2(int i){
          vector<int> v;
          v.push_back(i);
          return v[0];
        }

        int & func3(int i){
          array<int,4> arr;
          arr[0] = i;
          return arr[0];
        }

        int& func4(int i){
          int j = i;
          return j;
        }

    int main(){

      cout<<func(3)<<endl;
      cout<<func2(10)<<endl;
      cout<<func3(100)<<endl;
      cout<<func4(123)<<endl;

    return 0;
    }

outuput:
3
0
100
segmentation faul(core dumped)
```

calling func it's ok because while p is local *p is i ,and i lives in global scope(?).
calling func2 return 0, which thing does not make sense to me, i expected to have a segmentation fault since v is a local vector...
calling func3 returns the correct value, and this does not make sense either, for the same reason as above.
calling func4 finally does what i expected giving segmentatioun fault

can someone help me understand what happens in deep? why are vector and array working as they were declared as static ? in fact considering that all functions are returning reference, i expected to have segmentation fault since vector and array are local object, and they should be deleted once function ends.

very thanks

Comment: *None* of the functions in the code you show actually works (not even `func`), they all lead to *undefined behavior*. And once you have *undefined behavior* it's really no use in arguing.

Comment: _and i lives in global scope(?)_ What gave you that idea? In all of the examples, `i` is a variable that's local to the function.

Comment: i was supposing that since the output was coincidently matching the value i passed to to func.

Comment: then at this point my question is: what if i bind a local reference/pointer to a global variable ? is it ok?

Answer (score 5):

Undefined behavior is happening there. Returning local parameter or variable by reference is undefined behavior, the same way as returning an address to it.

Comment: thanks, than at this point my question is: is it correct to return local reference/pointer to global objects?

Answer (score 1):

If you desire or must return a reference, then use a static variable:

```
int& my_func(int variable)
{
  static int some_value = 0;
  some_value = variable;
  return some_value;
}
```

The keyword `static` tells the compiler that the variable will have a lifetime after execution leaves the function.

To return a reference, you need to *refer* to a variable that will not disappear after execution leaves a function.

Comment: thanks, then my question is, can i return local reference/pointer binded to global objects?

Comment: Yes, you can return references to global and file local variables.